# How do I simultaneously extract the F and Pvalue from this object from the grangertest() function?

Tags: r, statistics, extract

```
Model 1: DLPFc ~ Lags(DLPFc, 1:1) + Lags(IPs, 1:1)
Model 2: DLPFc ~ Lags(DLPFc, 1:1)
  Res.Df Df      F    Pr(>F)    
1   4597                        
2   4598 -1 88.522 < 2.2e-16 ***
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(lmtest)
data(ChickEgg)
(out <- grangertest(egg ~ chicken, order = 3, data = ChickEgg))
#Granger causality test

#Model 1: egg ~ Lags(egg, 1:3) + Lags(chicken, 1:3)
#Model 2: egg ~ Lags(egg, 1:3)
#  Res.Df Df      F Pr(>F)
#1     44                 
#2     47 -3 0.5916 0.6238
```

Extract F and p-values

```
out[, c("F", "Pr(>F)")]
#       F Pr(>F)
#1              
#2 0.5916 0.6238
```

If you want to exclude the empty first row, do `out[-1, c("F", "Pr(>F)")]`

---

If we don't want a new object and get the values right away we can do

```
unlist(grangertest(egg ~ chicken, order = 3, data = ChickEgg)[-1, c("F", "Pr(>F)")])
#        F    Pr(>F) 
#0.5916153 0.6237862
```

Which returns a named vector.

Comment: @BenBolker `lapply(out[, c("F", "Pr(>F)")], typeof)` gives "double" for both entries. Or do I miss your point?

Comment: Sorry about that. I was thrown off by the fact that (now that I tried it myself I see) it's an `anova()` object, so the `NA` values are printed as blanks.  It's fine the way it is.

Comment: Thanks! I do want just the numbers, so is there a way to do without creating another object like "out"

Comment: @M.M Updated the answer.

Comment: @markus,  this code I have here is not quite right.          GC1 <- matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
  colnames(GC1) <- c("F-stat", "P-Value")
  
  GC2 <- matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
  colnames(GC2) <- c("F-stat", "P-Value")
  

  for (i in 1:2) {
    GC1[i] <- unlist(grangertest(IPs, DLPFc, i)[-1, c("F", "Pr(>F)")])
    GC2[i] <- unlist(grangertest(DLPFc, IPs, i)[-1, c("F", "Pr(>F)")])

Comment: @M.M This seems to be a different question. I don't know `IPs` nor `DLPFc` so I can't help you. What I can say is that you're missing a `}` at the end.